# AWS Kinesis Analytics - Data Aggregation

Tags: amazon-web-services, analytics

Ive been looking at AWS Kinesis analytics for some time now, and I struggle to make a following scenario work:

Say you have a Firehose that is connected to Kinesis Analytics as input stream. 
This firehose is meant to output data **every 60s**. 
I write data into this Firehose **each 2s or so** like:
`{"value":1}`. 
Where the `1` is a random integer (can be 1, 5, 32 and so on). 
How can I write my analytics to say find average value of all values reported in last 60s and pass it to a lambda?

I tried using various windows - however the Analytics seems to output the data every few seconds, instead of once 60s.

Answer (score 0):

please have a look into the following links which have detailed examples how to achieve this.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/sqlref/sql-reference-avg.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/sqlref/sql-reference-windowed-aggregation-stream.html